# how to make a list stay permanently in android

Tags: android-listview

I am new to android programming and was trying to make an app that would take some data through the edit text from the user and would return a list of it using list view.I was successful in making it,but then I realized that when I make the list and close and reopen the app,the previous list gets deleted and and I have to start all over again.So could anyone tell me how to save the list without the use of the database.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save your data for further use, is creating a database.

here is a good tutorial for learning how to use database in android:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/